# Not selecting the id which unsatisfy condition using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table with RepId and date.

```
Table: 1
RepID   logTime
108981  2013-04-09 00:00:00.000
108981  2013-04-09 00:00:00.000
108981  2013-04-11 00:00:00.000
108981  2013-04-11 00:00:00.000
108981  2013-04-11 00:00:00.000
108982  2013-04-09 00:00:00.000
108982  2013-04-10 00:00:00.000
108982  2013-04-11 00:00:00.000
108982  2013-04-11 00:00:00.000
108982  2013-04-11 00:00:00.000
```

I want to regret the RepId from table 1 if atleast one date in date range specified in where condition didnot match.

I have written the query like

```
select tl.repID from table1 tl where 
     CONVERT(date, logTime) > CONVERT(date,'2013-04-08 00:00:00.000') and CONVERT(date, logTime) < CONVERT(date,'2013-04-12 00:00:00.000')
```

Here the output will be like

```
RepID
108981
108982
```

But I want it like

```
RepID
108982
```

As the repId - 108981 does not have the date '2013-04-10 00:00:00.000' specified in the where condition.

----or-----
How to take the RepID and date which is not satisfied.....

Please help to overcome this problem.........

Comment: Is this MySQL or MSSQL?

Comment: I'm pretty sure ["regret"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/regret) doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: I meant not taking up the values

Answer (score 2):

Try Like this...

```
SELECT RepID FROM (Select RepID ,(Select Count(Distinct Cast(logTime as Date)) FROM T as A 
   WHERE 
   Cast( a.logTime as date) > Cast('2013-04-08 00:00:00.000' as date) 
   and Cast( a.logTime as date) < Cast('2013-04-12 00:00:00.000' as Date)
    AND
  A.RepID=b.RepID) AS COUNTS
   FROM T as B) as  c 
    WHERE COUNTS=datediff('2013-04-12 00:00:00.000','2013-04-08 00:00:00.000')-1 
    group by RepID
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55be1/12)

Comment: If you just want the items with a record for all dates (or with minimal changes the items which does not use a date) then this is a better solution than mine. It should be quicker and cope with larger date ranges easily. Only down side is if you want to list out the dates that are not used but from the description this isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly get a range of dates and cross join that against your data. Count the number where there is a match on the dates, and if it isn't the same as the number of days between the dates then put it out.

Something like this (not tested)

```
SELECT tl.repID, SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(date, logTime) = Sub1.SomeDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MatchCount
FROM table1 tl 
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT DATE_ADD('2013-04-08',INTERVAL 1+a.i+b.i*10 DAY) SomeDate
FROM (SELECT 0 AS i
UNION SELECT 1 AS i
UNION SELECT 2 AS i
UNION SELECT 3 AS i
UNION SELECT 4 AS i
UNION SELECT 5 AS i
UNION SELECT 6 AS i
UNION SELECT 7 AS i
UNION SELECT 8 AS i
UNION SELECT 9 AS i) a,
(SELECT 0 AS i
UNION SELECT 1 AS i
UNION SELECT 2 AS i
UNION SELECT 3 AS i
UNION SELECT 4 AS i
UNION SELECT 5 AS i
UNION SELECT 6 AS i
UNION SELECT 7 AS i
UNION SELECT 8 AS i
UNION SELECT 9 AS i) b
HAVING  SomeDate < '2013-04-12' ) Sub1
GROUP BY tl.repID
HAVING MatchCount != 3
```

This will cope with up to 100 day date ranges but easily expanded.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the logic of your preposition: instead of 'regret' registers with dates inside the range, look for registers which dates are outside the range.